# DNS synonyms: multiple zones, one zone file

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone

I have a site with a bunch of synonym domains. The site itself accepts all the different domains, and redirects to the correct domain name.

Is there any reason not to configure `zones.conf` like so:

```
zone "correctdomain.com" {
  type master;
  file "correctdomain.zonefile";
};

zone "synonymdomain.com" {
  type master;
  file "correctdomain.zonefile";
};
```

There's nothing in the zone file itself that's tied to the domain name.

Comment: I don't really see a reason why this should not be allowed. If the zonefile containt the correct information there should be no issue I guess.

Comment: Does it work when you try it?

Comment: It appears to work, but that doesn't mean there isn't some horrid surprise lurking in the wings waiting to pounce after the site goes live.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely fine -- with one ***critically important*** caveat: You ***MUST*** use short names for your records.

```
foo                      IN    A      127.0.0.1             ; <-- This is fine.  
bar                      IN    CNAME  foo                   ; <-- This is fine.
baz                      IN    CNAME  foo.correctdomain.com ; <-- That's fine too.
@                        IN    A      127.0.0.2  ; <-- use @ for the base domain
                                                 ;     so it works everywhere
```

but

```
quux.correctdomain.com.   IN    A     127.0.0.1  ; <-- This will make BIND cry.
                                                 ; (because it's a bad name in
                                                 ;  synonymdomain.com's zone file)
```